# Please help me understand what the man said at 5:13 in this YouTube video

Tags: listening

What are the transcripts at 5:13 of this YouTube video "What Would You Do With A Lost Wallet" (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=haJDju3LafU)?

What I heard are:
5:13 That never happened. ??? that never ever happened.

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you just asking for someone to transcribe that section?

Comment: He says, "that never **happens.**" Simple present.

Comment: I think this is what he says: That never happens. Do you understand? Like, that never ever happens.

Comment: You can ask or discuss this type of questions in [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22937/the-english-learning-cabin) :D

Comment: This question is not good for ELL as I think!

Answer (score 1):

The speaker says, "that never happens."